# Let $f(x)$ be continuous everywhere and consider the function $g(x)$. Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f(x)$ be continuous everywhere and consider the function:
> $$g(x)=\begin{cases}f(x) &\text{if}\ f(x)>0\\0 &\text{if}\ f(x)\le0\end{cases}$$
> Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous everywhere.

Hello, can anyone please help me with this one? I have a feeling this has to do with composition but cannot figure out the correlation between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.
Thank you!

Comment: Hint:  Because the functions $f$ and $0$ are both continuous, you only need to check that $g$ is continuous at $x = 0$.

Comment: Actually I am struggling with that step you are talking about. Does the condition f(x)<0 play any roles in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint.

The function $g$ can be written as
$$
g(x)=\frac12(f(x)+|f(x)|)
$$

and $x\mapsto |x|$ is a continuous function.

You may want to recall that (whenever compatible)

- the sum of two continuous functions is continuous;
- the composition of two continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I did have a feeling this has to do with composition but cannot figure out the correlation between f(x) and g(x). You are savior!

Comment: @NhatNamNguyen: you are welcome!

Comment: Just one more question? How do you arrive to that correlation between f and g?

Comment: @NhatNamNguyen: you can do that by inspection. Or observe that $g=\max(f,0)$ and the fact that $\max(a,b)=\frac12 (a+b+|a-b|)$.

Comment: Looks more like a complete written solution than a hint to me...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the fact that $g(x) = \max \{f(x), 0\}$. The continuity of the functions involved is key.

Hope that helps,